# Distributivity of disjunction over implication

Tags: logic, solution-verification, propositional-calculus

Is the proof given below acceptable? I am trying to prove that the following logical formula is a tautology.

> **Formula.** $$((p \rightarrow q) \lor r) \equiv ((p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r))$$

**Proof.**

$$((p \rightarrow q) \lor r) \equiv ((p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r))$$
$$((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv (\lnot(p \lor r) \lor (q \lor r))$$
$$((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv ((\lnot p \land \lnot r) \lor (q \lor r))$$
$$((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv ((\lnot p \land \lnot r) \lor (r \lor q))$$
$$((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv ((( \lnot p \land \lnot r) \lor r) \lor q)$$
$$((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv (((\lnot p \lor r) \land (\lnot r \lor r)) \lor q)$$
$$((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv (((\lnot p \lor r) \land \top) \lor q)$$
$$((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv ((\lnot p \lor r) \lor q)$$
$$((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \equiv ((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) $$

Hence, the formula is tautology.

Comment: It looks correct.

Comment: It seems quicker to check this with a truth table. Quicker yet (if allowed) is the argument that (1) if $r$ is true then both sides of $\equiv$ are true, and (2) if $r$ is false then both sides reduce to $p\to q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Technically, to prove $$((p \rightarrow q) \lor r) \equiv ((p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r))$$ is to prove that $$((p \rightarrow q) \lor r) \leftrightarrow ((p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r))$$ is a tautology.)

Allow me to condense your presentation:
$$[(p \lor r) \rightarrow (q \lor r)]
\\\equiv [\lnot(p \lor r) \lor (q \lor r)]
\\\equiv [(\lnot p \land \lnot r) \lor (q \lor r)]
\\\equiv [(\lnot p \lor (q \lor r)) \land (\lnot r \lor (q \lor r))]
\\\equiv [((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \land (\lnot r \lor q \lor r)]
\\\equiv [((\lnot p \lor q) \lor r) \land \top]
\\\equiv [(\lnot p \lor q) \lor r]
\\\equiv [(p \rightarrow q) \lor r].\quad\text{(proved)}$$

Comment: In some logic systems, the $\equiv$ is a logic symbol, not a logic symbol, i.e. it is used for the material biconditional rather than for logical equivalence. Given the OP's question, in which he uses the $\equiv$ in a formula, and is then asked to prove that that formula is a tautology, that seems to be the case here.  Yeah, I hate the fact that different texts trreat symbols differently!!

Comment: @Bram28 I guess it’s opportune to air my usual disclaimer postscript: Symbolic logic is an area rife with conflicting notation, terminology and even notions; my understanding is eclectically evolving.

Comment: I know ... if there was one area where you'd expect absolutely rigorous standard it'd be logic .... :P